# System.Management.Automation dll throws ItemNotFoundException on Appx calls

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a very strange issue.  I have added a reference to System.Management.Automation in my project and I am trying to call the following code:

```
using (Powershell ps = Powershell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript("Get-AppxPackage");
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

Note that I can run other powershell commands in this way fine, it is only the Appx commands that are raising an exception.  Running the Get-AppxPackage command results in an ItemNotFoundException.  The error is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules' because it does not exist.

My first assumption was that this may be a working directory thing, so I explicitly set the working directory before calling the command, but that did not change anything.  I then checked, and that directory did not exist, so I created it just to see what would happen.  After creating the directory and running the code again I got this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find path 'C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Appx\Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands' because it does not

I honestly have no idea what is going on here.  To make the issue even stranger, I tried this on another computer and the code works fine.  So there must be something wrong with Visual Studio or my project on that one computer.

I've tried deleting the debug and obj folder, the suo and all of that.  I've removed the reference to System.Management.Automation and re-added it, even rebooting in between.  I am at a loss, I have no idea why this is happening or what else I can do to figure it out.

Note:  I am able to run the Appx commands in Powershell ISE fine, so there is no issue on the computer.  The problem is only with calling that command through the System.Management.Automation dll.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try running it as administrator? that's sometimes could be the problem

Comment: Thatnks for the suggestion.  I have tried this.  Unfortunately running as admin did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it appears that this issue was caused by installing the incorrect version of System.Management.Automation as a nuget package via the package manager.  I had uninstalled this and then added a reference to the latest version of the DLL manually before I started getting the issue described above.

But the uninstall for the nuget package clearly didn't work properly as the project continued to reference this version, and nothing I tried could get it to use the new one.

To solve the issue, I created a new project, added the source files, added a reference directly to the new version of System.Management.Automation and the error stopped occuring.

I can only assume that the installing and uninstalling the wrong version with the package manager corrupted the first project.